# How to map a Map<String,Double>

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, hibernate-annotations

I tried

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
Map<String, Double> data = new HashMap<String, Double>();
```

but it produces the error :

```
   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.company.Klass.data[java.lang.Double]
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1016)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:567)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.MapBinder$1.secondPass(MapBinder.java:80)
at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:43)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1130)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:296)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1115)
```

any idea?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, the error message is pretty clear: `Double` isn't an entity. If you want to map a collection of basic elements, use the `CollectionOfElement` annotation (from Hibernate) or the `ElementCollection` annotation (from JPA 2.0).

So, assuming you're using Hibernate Annotations 3.4, try this:

```
@CollectionOfElements(targetElement = Double.class)
@org.hibernate.annotations.MapKey(targetElement = String.class)
Map data;
```

Or, when using generics:

```
@CollectionOfElements
Map<String, Double> data;
```

And if you're using Hibernate Annotations 3.5+, prefer the JPA 2.0 annotations:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Double.class)
@MapKeyClass(String.class)
Map data;
```

Or, when using generics:

```
@ElementCollection
Map<String, Double> data;
```

#### References

- Hibernate Annotations 3.4 Reference Guide

  - [2.4.6.2.2. Map](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.4/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection-extratype-map)
  - [2.4.6.2.5. Collection of element or composite elements](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.4/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2770)
- JPA 2.0 specification

  - Section 11.1.12 "ElementCollection Annotation"
  - Section 11.1.28 "MapKeyClass Annotation"

---

> Do you know how to customize the "ELEMENT" and "MAPKEY" column names ?

You can fully customize the result. I think the sample below demonstrates everything:

```
@CollectionOfElements(targetElement = Double.class)
@JoinTable(name = "COLLECTION_TABLE", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID"))
@org.hibernate.annotations.MapKey(targetElement = String.class, 
    columns = @Column(name = "SOME_KEY"))
@Column(name = "SOME_VALUE")
private Map data;
```

- The name of the collection table for the `Map` is defined using the `JoinTable`

  - The name of the column for the key to the parent is set using a `JoinColumn` in the `JoinTable`
- The name of the column for the key of the map is defined in the `MapKey`
- The name of the column for the value of the map is defined using the `Column`

Comment: Thank you so much ! Do you know how to customize the "ELEMENT" and "MAPKEY" column names ?

Comment: When using
@ElementCollection
Map<String, Double> data;
I get this error in hbm2ddl: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Map, at table: MYTABLE, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(MYFIELD)]

Comment: @Wouter Open a question, mention the version of Hibernate, etc (but the above answer is correct, as per the JPA 2.0 specification).

Comment: Problem still exists, so I've followed your suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096525/mapping-a-mapstring-double-with-hibernate-and-jpa

Comment: @org.hibernate.annotations.MapKey(targetElement = String.class, 
    columns = @Column(name = "SOME_KEY"))
is deprecated:
@MapKeyColumn(name="SOME_KEY")
should work in its stead